# 'Expected Expression' error when initializing multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, declaration

I have read several tutorials about multidimensional arrays. All of them gives the same pattern for declaring multi-array variable, which looks like this:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
```

But when I use this pattern, I get error in Firebug:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'
```

With the arrow pointing at [ ][ ]

WebStorm shows following errors:

```
Expression statement is not assignment or call
```

for the first int
and

```
expression expected
```

for [ ][ ]

and JSLint:

```
Unexpected ']'
```

Question: how to initialize two-dimensional array properly?

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Javascript? My guess is Javascript, given the context - in which case you should delete the `java` tag. Java and Javascript are entirely different languages.

Comment: JavaScript. Thanks for correction.

Comment: There are no static types in javascript. It really looks like you are trying to write something java-like in a javascript environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java**: The shown example is totally correct. 
`int[][] multi = new int[5][10]` and `int multi [][] = new int[5][10]` both work. You can always initialize it by hand (a tedious process) or better with a simple for-loop iteration.

**JavaScript**: Since I am not so much acquainted with the PL, I will give you some general examples of how to declare such array.

```
var multi = new Array([]);
multi[0][0] = 'Hi data';
alert(multi[0][0]);
```

But in general *There are no two dimensional arrays in Javascript.* You can create only an empty jagged array.

Or easier from start : `var multi = [[],[],[]];`